# ODP.Net Connection Pooling

Tags: oracle, database-connection, connection-string, odp.net

We are working with connection pool and we set the max pool size to be 300.
for some unknown reason there are many situations in which `select count(*) from v$session where program = 'w3wp.exe'` gives us a bigger number than 300 (I see now 330 for instance).

How is it possible? How can I troubleshoot such thing?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to say, but you should definitely be turning on connection pool counters and monitoring them with performance monitor. See: https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT174

Comment: I did that but still didn't get a clear answer. It seems like even if there are free open connections, new connections are created.